# Why am I wrong about this dynamics question?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, free-body-diagram

I disagree with the answer to this homework question. Here it goes.

> The coefficient of static friction is 0.60 between the two blocks in
>   figure. The coefficient of kinetic friction between the lower block
>   and the floor is 0.20. Force F⃗  causes both blocks to cross a
>   distance of 5.0m , starting from rest.
>
> What is the least amount of time in which this motion can be completed
>   without the top block sliding on the lower block?

[image: sliding blocks]

Here's how I did it. I calculated the maximum force that won't cause the blocks to slide. The answer I got was **23.52N**. So far the cannonical answer agrees with me.

Now I subtract the force of friction on the bottom block (13.72N) from the total tension on the rope and get **9.8N** . The answer still agrees with me.

Here's where it diverges. To find the acceleration I take the net force (9.8N) and using F=ma where m = (mass of top block + mass of bottom block = 7kg), I get an acceleration of **1.4m/s^2**

The answer key uses F=ma, but instead of taking m as mass of both blocks they take m to be the mass of the bottom block alone so they get an acceleration of **3.27m/s^2**. Why are they doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Here's how I did it. I calculated the maximum force that won't cause the blocks to slide. The answer I got was 23.52N.

Your answer key is correct. You made a mistake in the above. That value is not the maximum value of the force $\vec F$. It is instead the maximum value of the force of static friction between the two blocks. It's a very good idea to identify all of the forces and all of the constraints. A free body diagram sometimes helps in this regard.

There are two horizontal forces acting on the top block, the external force $F$ (directed forward) and the frictional force $F_1$ (directed backwards) between the two blocks. The net force on the top block is thus $F-F_1$, making the acceleration of the top block $\frac{F-F_1}{4\,\text{kg}}$. There are two horizontal forces acting on the bottom block, the frictional forces $F_1$ (directed forward) and $F_2$ (directed backwards). The net force on the bottom  block is thus $F_1-F_2$, making the acceleration of the bottom block $\frac{F_1-F_2}{3\,\text{kg}}$.

We want the two blocks to accelerate as one, so $a = \frac{F-F_2}{7 kg} = \frac{F-F_1}{4\,\text{kg}} = \frac{F_1-F_2}{3\,\text{kg}}$. There's an easy way to solve this problem and two harder ways to solve it. The easy way is to just look at the bottom block. We know the forces $F_1$ and $F_2$; they're $0.6\cdot 4\,\text{kg} \cdot 9.8\,\text{m}/\text{s}^2 = 23.52\, \text{N}$ and $0.2\cdot 7\,\text{kg} \cdot 9.8\,\text{m}/\text{s}^2 = 13.72\, \text{N}$. The bottom block (and hence the stack) accelerates at $a = \frac{F_1-F_2}{3\,\text{kg}} = \frac {9.8} 3\,\text{m}/\text{s}^2$.

The two hard ways that I mentioned above? Those would involve solving for the acceleration of the stack, $\frac{F - F_2}{7\,\text{kg}}$, or the acceleration of the top block $\frac{F - F_1}{4\,\text{kg}}$. You'll need to solve for $F$ before you can use these expressions. Why bother when you don't need to do that?

Comment: So just to check that I understand what's going on. If the bottom block were immobile, and I applied pulled on the rope with more than 23.52N, the top block would slip. However since the bottom block is accelerating as well, I can pull on the rope with 23.52N + the amount of extra force necessary to make the top block accelerate at the same rate as the bottom block and the blocks won't slip?

Comment: That's correct.